# Can OSB scraps be used as kindling in an open outdoor fire pit?

Tags: fire-pit, osb

This question is about an open, outdoor, non-cooking fire pit.   Not about indoors, stoves, fire places, or cooking.  I have a lot of OSB scraps.  I buy wood for the fire pit regularly.  Should I use the OSB in the fire pit, or throw it away?  Is burning it a bad practice ?   (Relative to burning logs that is).

Comment: What grade of OSB? Anyway a cursory google search shows that the main chemical in OSB glue is formaldehyde. Putting that in the air around the campfire seems problematic to me.

Comment: I can't provide anything like an authoritative answer, but when I'm around a fire, I can smell it, which means that stuff from the fire is getting into my nose/lungs... I'm not sure if all those resins/binders are beneficial.

Comment: As with most things, it would depend on the amount.  A few pieces of kindling will be a lot different than wheelbarrows of the stuff burnt at the same time.  Close neighbours with breathing problems should also be taken in account if you do decide to burn, a small amount might affect them worst than you.

Comment: Treated wood should not be burnt.

Comment: Although I have burned much OSB and plywood I don’t think it is a good idea where people are gathered around, I don’t have specific data stating it produces toxic fumes and believe most building materials are designed to not be hazardous but many do produce toxic gasses when burned, prior to recommendation’s on burning in a group atmosphere I would check just to be sure